# Почему volumes в docker-compose перетирают содержимое директории внутри контейнера ?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: test/vitrina_20:$VITRINA_RELEASE
    command: ['./init.sh']
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/vitrina_20/static:/code/static
      - /var/www/html/vitrina_20/media:/code/media
      - /var/log/vitrina_20:/code/logs
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    environment:
      - DATANRM_URL
      - DATANRM_USER
      - DATANRM_PASS
```

Имеется docker-compose файл.
1. Почему при запуске docker-compose.yml файла затирается содержимое папки static внутри контейнера ? 
**2. Как сделать чтобы содержимое папки /code/static в том виде в котором оно существует в репозитории было проброшено в папку /var/www/html/vitrina_20/static на хостсистему ?** 
В не запущенном состоянии я вижу содержимое папки:

```
ls -1 static/
admin
bootstrap.bundle.min.js
bootstrap.min.css
bootstrap.min.js
debug_toolbar
favicon.ico
main.css
mptt
```

После запуска compose, когда я захожу внутрь контейнера я вижу что содержимое папки пустое и тем не менее в процессе работы я могу создать какой то файл в static и он пробросится на хост систему.

Comment: Потому что происходит **перекрытие** (не перетирание) пустой папкой хоста.

Answer (score 3):

> Почему при запуске docker-compose.yml файла затирается содержимое папки static внутри контейнера?

происходит не «затирание», а [монтирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount#mount_--bind).

> Как сделать чтобы содержимое папки /code/static в том виде в котором оно существует в репозитории было проброшено в папку /var/www/html/vitrina_20/static на хостсистему?

например, смонтировать этот каталог (`/code/static`) туда, куда вам надо.

1. путь к корневой файловой системе существующего контейнера можно получить командой `inspect` программы *docker*:

   ```
   $ docker inspect --format="{{.GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir}}" идентификатор-контейнера
   ```
2. посмотреть содержимое `/code/static`, соответственно, можно так:

   ```
   $ sudo ls $(docker inspect --format="{{.GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir}}" идентификатор-контейнера)/code/static
   ```
3. примонтировать так:

   ```
   $ sudo mount --bind $(docker inspect --format="{{.GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir}}" идентификатор-контейнера)/code/static /куда/монтировать
   ```

---

конечно, не забывайте отмонтировать таким образом примонтированные каталоги **до** уничтожения контейнера.

---

но вообще это, конечно, неправильный путь. постоянные данные должны храниться либо непосредственно в каталоге хост-системы, либо в [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).