# Docker, Jenkins, Volume + проброс конфинга

Tags: docker, jenkins

Имеется docker контейнер с jenkins на котором происходит сборка проекта используя docker, который потом заливается на свой docker registry.

Сборка образа осуществляется на основном хосте (там же где и стоит сам докер с jenkins-ом) (исходники были склонированы внутри контейнера jenkins).

Суть вопроса: как правильно пробросить конфинг внутрь контейнера для нормального запуска, если сам конфинг лежит в jenkins контейнере вместе с исходниками?

На данный момент, пробросить в контейнер конфинг не получается (путь указываеться с переменной WORKSPACE)

Comment: совершенно непонятно, что именно вызывает у вас трудности, и, соостветственно, чем вам можно помочь.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я конечно понимаю, что не доступно объяснил, но вы хотя бы уточните, какой вам момент не понятен. Суть в том что при запуске используя docker run с ключем -v файл с конфингом пробросить не может. Я так понимаю, причина в том что докер не может получить доступ к файлам так как они внутри контейнера с jenkins. Вопрос в том, как правильно пробрасывать конфинг

Comment: вы опять очень смутно объяснили, потому, если ошибаюсь — то извините. насколько я понял, вы не последовали [советам разработчиков](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md) и не разместили т.н. «jenkins home» ни в отдельном каталоге (вариант 1), ни в выделенном *docker volume* (вариант 2). иначе никаких проблем с монтированием файлов-каталогов (в.1) или подключением томов (в.2) к новым контейнерам у вас бы не возникло. // ну, можно, в конце концов примонтировать и «[докеровские потроха](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/825349/178576)». хотя лучше, конечно, сделать как советуют.